# Rails form populated from one table and saving to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Title kinda says it all, Basically i have this form

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Editing event:
  <%= @newevent.id %></h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= simple_form_for @newevent do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventname %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventname, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :event_type, :collection => ['Concert','Festival','Sports','Theatre'] %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventdesc %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventdesc, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventshortdesc %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventshortdesc, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :pagetitle %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :pagetitle, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :metatag %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :metatag, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventvenuename %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventvenuename, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :time, type: "time", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :date, type: "date", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventimage %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventimage, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-info" %>
<%= link_to "Delete", event_path(@newevent), :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what it loads from.

```
  def edit
    @newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
```

However its different now. I am wanting the stuff to load form the `Master` table (so the fields are populated from `Master`) However i have an update method that looks like this

```
  def update
    @newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @newevent.update_attributes(event_params.merge createdby: current_user.id)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to "/events"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Error updating event'
    end
  end
```

Do i need to change something in the eventparams to get this to work (and make change from `Event` to `Master`) The fields are different in both tables, So would i need to make the value of the fields be something like this?

```
value: "<%=Master.name%>"
```

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Your question is not more clearer, actually what you need

Comment: Basically i need it to load in defaults into the form from one table and save to another. (its loading the defaults from an edit button that has the id on it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load "defaults", you'd be better doing it in the model layer:

```
#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_defaults

   private

   def set_defaults
     default = Master.first
     self.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at").each do |field|
       self[field] ||= default.send(field)
     end
   end
end
```

The above will pull a record from the `Master` model, populate any of the `attributes` in your `Event` model which have not been populated.

---

*However*, I believe your pattern to be inefficient.

The idea you are pulling "default" data from another model/table directly contradicts the [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [`modular`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design#Design_Concepts) principles of software development.

Not to say that if you wanted to create "dynamic" defaults for a model, your pattern might work. If you're trying to store *exactly the same* data in different models, you've got a problem.

I would do the following:

```
#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   @@defaults: {
     x: "y",
     y: "z",
     z: "0"
   }

   before_create :set_defaults

   private

   def set_defaults
     self.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at").each do |field|
       self[field] ||= @@defaults[field]
     end      
   end
end
```

---

**Update**

After a discussion, it became apparent that there was more context required to understand the issue/solution fully.

The app works by importing a series of `CSV` data into the `Master` table. Whilst I don't know what data this is, the OP said that each `Event` would be built *around* the data in `Master`.

He mentioned he needed *3* fields definitely from `Master` whilst the others could be inputted by the user into `Event`.

This means that you could tie the two together with a [`has_many` / `belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) relationship:

```
#app/models/master.rb
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :events
end

#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :master
end
```

This is a standard [`ActiveRecord association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which means you'll be able to call `@master.events` & `@event.master` -- accessing values from each table:

```
#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @event = Event.new
   end

   def create
      @event = Event.new event_params
      @event.save
   end

   private

   def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:master_id, ...)
   end
end

#app/views/events/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :master_id, Master.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

The reason why this will be much better than your current pattern is that each time you create a new `event`, you'll be able to access the `master` attributes:

```
@event.master.url #-> "url" from master record
```

Comment: Hi Rich, Thats what i'm trying to avoid, The DRY. 

I'm beginning to wonder if i should look at this a different way. Its only 3 fields in the database table that needs to be populated into the form. the rest are kept blank.

Comment: Can you give me some more context? What are you trying to make / build, how should it work?

Comment: Basically i have two tables, The Master table and the Event Table, The Master table has loads of data in. The Events doesnt. I have the Master table showing in a view. I'm wanting some data from the Master table to populate the form. This would then save to the Events table

Comment: Why do you have a `Master` table? Why don't you just store the defaults in a constant or class var?

Comment: because the Master table has around 40k rows inside, The defaults change depending on what row its on (via the ID)

Comment: Want to go to chat about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102587/discussion-between-samadmit-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 0):

In Rails in general you create bound form inputs by using a model and passing it to `form_for` (or `simple_form_for`).

In this case if you **really** need to have dynamic user editable default the most obvious solution would be to use Master to seed the new Event.

In most cases however defaults should be a developer concern which are handled on the model layer as suggested by Rich Peck.

Also setting defaults only really makes sense for a new record - why would you want to override the users choices when updating?

```
def new
  @master = Master.last
  @event = Event.new(@master.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at"))
end
```

---

```
<%= simple_form_for @newevent do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :eventname %>
<% end %>
```